# What is a blowfish secret in phpMyAdmin?

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, blowfish

About setting up the config.inc.php, the official phpMyAdmin docs says

```
$cfg['blowfish_secret'] = 'theExampleWrites16ValuesHere';  // use here a value of your choice
```

What is a blowfish secret?
How do I generate, or choose, a value?

Answer (score 26):

Simply use any random string of characters and/or numbers that you like. It is a value that will be unique to your instance and use of phpMyAdmin.

Comment: According to the docs "a key length of 32 is recommended." ([link](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/phpMyAdmin#Add_blowfish_secret_passphrase)). If you use a string that is too short, an error message might show up on some versions of phpmyamdin.

Comment: Interestingly, if I put _more_ than 32 characters, the PHP module dies with 'Bus Error' (on FreeBSD at least). Less than that, of course, triggers the 'Blowfish secret is too short' error.

Comment: @GwynethLlewelyn With what version of PHP and phpMyAdmin? Using PHP 7.3.rc6 and phpMyAdmin 4.8.3 mine is far more than 32 characters and doesn't have any issues.

Comment: [PhpMyAdmin Blowfish generator](https://www.motorsportdiesel.com/tools/blowfish-salt/pma/)

Answer (score 5):

The [doc](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#cookie-authentication-options) describes what blowfish secret is in phpMyAdmin,

> The “cookie” auth_type uses AES algorithm to encrypt the password. If
> you are using the “cookie” auth_type, enter here a random passphrase
> of your choice. It will be used internally by the AES algorithm: you
> won’t be prompted for this passphrase.
>
> The secret should be 32 characters long. Using shorter will lead to
> weaker security of encrypted cookies, using longer will cause no harm.

**So you can use any 32 or longer chain of characters for this purpose**. Even though the doc says a longer key wouldn't cause any harm, it apparently expects a key exactly 32 chars long.

You can use,

```
$ openssl rand -base64 22
```

or any other random string generator to generate random 32 chars long key. And use it as the value as in the following example,

```
$cfg['blow_secret'] = '7yRxkscr/SB4Sb729H7HdnbNqZxJOQ==';
```

Answer (score 3):

Go to phpMyadmin Directory and open the config file >>  **/phpMyadmin/config.inc.php**

Locate >> *$cfg['blowfish_secret'] = ''; /* YOU MUST FILL IN THIS FOR COOKIE AUTH! */*

Enter a string which should be not less than 32 characters. {You can include Number, Characters&SpecialCharacters} Save and reload the page (//yourdomainname.*/phpmyadmin) and log in again. That should fix the error.

Ref: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PhpMyAdmin#Add_blowfish_secret_passphrase

Thanks and Regards

Answer (score 3):

go to /var/lib/phpmyadmin/blowfish_secret.inc.php and add some caracters to be 32 in length like this:

```
$cfg['blow_secret'] = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
```

save file and refresh phpMyAdmin.

Comment: on Debian 9.6 + Nginx, I had to chown it,too: `chown -R nginx:nginx /var/lib/phpmyadmin`

Answer (score 3):

If you have PHP available, you can add this to a shell script to build out the phpMyAdmin installation:

```
export SECRET=`php -r 'echo base64_encode(random_bytes(24));'`
echo "\$cfg['blowfish_secret'] = '$SECRET';" \
    >> /path/to/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php
```

Answer (score 1):

in `/usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/vendor_config.php` the config dir variable might either be empty or missing the trailing slash, change it into:

```
define('CONFIG_DIR', '/etc/phpmyadmin/');
```

The permission to this temporary directory needs to be set correctly in /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/vendor_config.php. It solved it for me. define('TEMP_DIR', '/var/lib/phpmyadmin/tmp/');

Also if you are missing the Users tab in PhpMyAdmin, it is caused because of insufficient rights. Run `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'myuser'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;`  from the mysql console (your your own administrative username) while logged in with root privileges.

Answer (score 0):

HELP TO USERS WHICH FILESYSTEM DO NOT SET FILE PERMISSIONS.

The file /config.inc.php must be set with chmod 755 in order to be accepted. Unfortunatelly, some disks and mounted filesystems will not accept chmod, so this file must remain as a "sample" /config.sample.inc.php.

You have a workaround to set all the configs in /libraries/config.default.php
They say you should not edit the file, but in my case was the unique option.